# Please help me read a file and count how many specific letter in it JAVA

Tags: java, file, character

This is my method so far. I tried to count an A letter in a file called in.txt.

```
public void countFile() {

  BufferedReader reader;
  int counter=0;

  try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));
  } 
  catch(IOException ioException) {
    System.err.println("Error Opening File: Terminating");
    System.exit(1);
  }
  int data = reader.read();  
  while(data != -1) {
    char charToSearch = 'A';

    //this is the part i mess up and i dont know how to fix it the char data have to be int and the char to search is char.

    if(charToSearch = (char) data); {
      counter++;
    }
  };
  reader.close();

  System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Thanks yall for helping me. I have been trying so hard but i cant fix it.

Comment: (1) What's the Java operator to compare two values for equality?  (2) What's the correct syntax of an `if` statement?

Comment: There is a difference between `=` and `==` and `while() {...};` is just wrong

Comment: (3) You have a loop that keeps going until `data` is `-1`.  But where in your loop is `data` ever changed?

Comment: Thank you yall. Yall are the best community I have ever had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the `if` issue mentioned by @ajb and @thegauravmahawar, we also need to handle exceptions correctly. Besides, we need to handle the while loop to read from BufferedReader properly, as suggested by @ajb. Here is the code:

```
public void countFile() {
    BufferedReader reader;
    int counter = 0;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));
        int data;
        while ((data = reader.read()) != -1) {
            char charToSearch = 'A';
            if (charToSearch == (char) data) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(counter);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.err.println("Error Opening File: Terminating");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeoKao Thanks a lot! And also thanks all commenters for hints!